# Missing End tag For Body or Envelope

Tags: java-me

When I run the j2me application which needs to call webservice for getting the response,
I receive `java.rmi.MarshalException:(1)Missing End tag For Body or Envelope`.
It does not give any error while running in the emulator but throws error when run in Nokia E5